# How to overcome duplicate URLS

Tags: google, google-search-console, redirects, robots.txt, duplicate-content

I am having a website which is 3 years old, now I wanted to do some SEO chages into it. so, changed the some urls.

From: `/psd-layouts.html` to `/psd-web-layouts.html`

Now my question is that, I had redirect request from first one to second one, but still when checked in Google Webmaster Tools (HTML Improvements section) it shows me that duplicates of the title and meta.

So what should I do for overcome of this situation. I thought that I have to put canonical tag or put first URL in robots.txt but still I am confused for this..

If i would go for canonical tag then How can I put it out:

please input your expert thoughts here

Answer (score 1):

If it's just a different URL, I personally would do a 301 redirect from the old to the new URL.

If that's not possible put a canonical tag like this in the `head` part of the **old** page:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="NEW URL"/>
```

Do not change the robots.txt. This will only tell Google (and other SE) not to crawl the old page - but will not prevent listing it in the index.

All changes do take a few days to be seen and reported by Google Webmaster Tools anyway - be patient.

Comment: Hello patrick thanks for answer,
See, now my page targeted page is "/services/website-designing/psd-web-layouts.html" not this "/services/website-designing/psd-layouts.html".... so where can I put canonical tag? should it be in taregeted page only... ? or both having same contents, so canonical is the best solution for this? please solve this

Comment: Hi Jimmy - if it's really the same content put a 301 redirect into the old page ".../psd-layouts.html" - if that's not possible put the canonical `<link rel="canonical" href="/services/website-designing/psd-web-layouts.html"/>` in the old page.

Comment: see I have already redirected 301 this url **/services/website-designing/psd-layouts.html** to **/services/website-designing/psd-web-layouts.html**. and now I am already going to optimized this url...

**/services/website-designing/psd-web-layouts.html**  but it still show duplicate meta description and duplicate title in Google webmaster tool..

so it is good to put canonical tag.. if yes then in which url I have to put canonical tag?

Comment: ok - keep the 301 redirect. Do not change anything, but wait a bit. As long as Google can crawl all pages on your website it will pick up the change within a few days or weeks. This depends on how often and how fast Googlebot is visiting your website. Maybe have a look at your logfiles if Googlebot already called the old page and got the 301 redirect.

Comment: its almost 3 months up. can you please help me form where I can check logfiles?

Comment: 3 months is too long - if you want to, you can send me the full URL as private message and I will have a look at it. Do you have full access to the server - or is it some shared/virtual/managed hosting? On Linux you usually have the logs in something like /var/log/httpd.

Comment: please give me your email id..